# Make "class" transient or serializable BUT the class is serializable

Tags: java, serialization, sonarqube

SonarQube 5.1 marks a lot of critical issues after reviewing my code. However the class itself and the referenced class in the field is also serializable. The referenced class inherits the serializable interface through a class.

Here is my example

```
public class A implements Serializable {
     private B b;  // -> Sonarcube markes this field as not serialzable
}
```

And the class B is defined as follows

```
public class B extends C {
 ....
}
```

And the class C is defined as follows

```
public abstract class C extends D {
 ....
}
```

And the class D is defined

```
public abstract class D implements Serializable {
  ....
}
```

Running FindBugs on the same project does not see these problems.
I am not sure if it is a bug in sonarcube or is my code has some other problems (other fields in the classes C,D or something else)

Does anybody has a clue ?

Comment: Do you provide bytecode correctly to SonarQube ? (with a Q)

Comment: What do you mean by 'Do you provide bytecode correctly to SonarQube ?' ?

Comment: The classes C and D are packaged in a seperate JAR file which is in the pom file used to compile, package, ...

Comment: How is the SonarQube analysis ran ? using maven or sonar-runner ? Which version of the sonar-java plugin are you using ?

Comment: It is run through maven. Not the sonar-runner

Comment: <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5</version>
        </plugin>

Comment: This is the version of the maven plugin, not the version of the sonar-java plugin. This version is displayed in the log of the analysis.

Answer (score 4):

It is probably because the binary files are not provided correctly. I had a similar issue with my SonarQube configuration, then I discovered that the classes that implement `Serializable` are in different modules and/or in an external library.

Setting correct values for `sonar.java.binaries` and `sonar.java.libraries` allow SonarQube to locate the binaries and correctly determine whether or not the classes are serializable.

Comment: where sonar.java.binaries present in SonarCubes setup?

Answer (score 0):

Just because some base class is implementing `Serializable` does not mean that automatically all derived classes are correctly serializable. Derived classes should define there own `serialVersionUid`. Also derived classes could introduce new field whose values might not be serializable.

So unless SonarQube has a hint that the author actually meant the class to be serializable (possibly by restating `implements Serializable` or by declaring `serialVersionUid`) it is correct for SonarQube to be suspicios about it by Liskovs substition principle.

However the  classification as critical could be something that needs discussion. But that is too opinion based for here.