# Fields in a "Serializable" class should either be transient or serializable squid : S1948

Tags: java, serialization, sonarqube

I am running into the below issue, please let me know if anyone has seen this before, really driving me crazy on how to move forward.

I have two entities-

```
    public class A implements Serializable{
    private String one;
    private String two;
    private java.util.Date date; 
    }
    public class B implements Serializable{
    private A a;
    private String three;
    }
```

When i run SonarQube Analysis on class B, I am seeing S1948 popping up, I am just not sure what else can i do here, Class A and B are serializable and do have all member fields which are serializable as well.

Please do let me know If this has been tackled before.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are those two classes in the same file ? if not is the bytecode of class A provided to the analysis ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make "class" transient or serializable BUT the class is serializable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29507980/make-class-transient-or-serializable-but-the-class-is-serializable)

Comment: @benzonico, what is meant by "bytecode of class A provided to analysis", please elaborate, I am using eclipse sonar plugin for analysis

Comment: @sanjay.singh, have you got any solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit late for this one, but I just found what was reported as a bug in the jira of the java plugin for sonar : 
https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1266

Basically, it says that S1948 will be raised if, at the time of the analyse, the bytecode is not available for the referred type.

If it is your problem, it could mean that A is not found on the classpath when analysing bytecode of the B class.